# Read file and make every character in a separate column

Tags: r, readr

I have a huge file (square data file of a sequence alignment) and want to put every position into a separate column, but `readr::read_delim` for instance can´t take empty delimiters, and for `readr::read_fwf` it seems that you need to specify every position? I have more than 35000 positions.

Example input file:

`EIGMEYRTVSGVAGPLVILDKVKGPKYQEI.....
EIGMEYRTVSGVAGPLVILDKVKGPKYQEI.....
EIGMEYRTVSGVAGPLVILDKVKGPKYQEI.....`

Output:

`col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6....
   E    I    G    M    E    Y.....
   E    I    G    M    E    Y.....
   E    I    G    M    E    Y.....`

Comment: what do you mean by every position? give us an example of the data and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Maybe use `readLines()`, then `strsplit(myDF$myCol, split = "")`. Please provide example input text file and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add an example. But basically I just want make a new column for every vertical position/character in the input file.

Comment: It's not like you have to type 35000 ones for `read.fwf`, just  `widths = rep(1, 35000)`. If you need to count the characters, do it with a system command, e.g., `system("head -n 1 yourfile | wc -m")` if you're on a unix-alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readr::read_fwf` has [a few different ways](http://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_fwf.html) you can specify the field widths using the `col_positions` argument. Here's a test file, `test.txt`:

```
Hdvsmf
Dfhjds
Dfhjkd
Dfklds
Dkjffd
Dsfjkd
fkldsf
```

Assuming you know how many fields there are, you can either specify a vector of field widths (1 character wide, 5 times because there are five fields in this test file):

```
read_fwf('test.txt', col_positions = fwf_widths(rep(1, 5)))
```

This is probably easier than specifying star and end positions for each field. You can also provide a character vector of column names to `fwf_widths`, like:

```
fwf_widths(rep(1, 5), paste0('col', 1:5))
```

If you don't know how many fields you have, you can also bring it in as a single column and then use [`tidyr::separate`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) to extract your columns (the `sep` argument can take a vector of numeric positions, not just delimiters):

```
# a data frame with everything in one column named blah
df1 = read_csv('test.txt', col_names = 'blah')
field_count = length(df1$blah[1]) # assuming the fields are all same length!

# nb: parentheses for field_count - 1 are super important! you will spend forever debugging this if you miss it
df1 = df1 %>% separate(blah, into = paste0('col', 1:field_count), sep = 1:(field_count - 1))
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thanks!

Comment: No worries! :D :D